# How to delete Cookie after clicking on reset button?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am saving checked state of checkboxes in cookie. I want to reset all checkboxes to unchecked on clicking reset button. javascript i am using reset the checkboxes but when i refresh page checked state coming back.

HTML :

```
    <form method="GET" name="frm1" action="filter.php" id="form">
    <input type="reset" onclick="return resetForm();"/>

    <div  class="" style="display:inline-block; margin-left:15px;" >
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input ids" name="search[]" value="sub1">
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <span class="custom-control-description" >sub1</span>
        </label><br>

        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input ids" name="search[]" value="sub2">
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <span class="custom-control-description">sub2</span>
        </label><br> 

    </div>  
    </form>
```

script:

```
    <script> 

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var chks = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="search[]"]');

    for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
        if (getCookie('search[' + chks[i].value + ']') == 'true') {
        chks[i].checked = true;
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
        chks[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.cookie = "search[" + this.value + "]=" + this.checked + "; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2018 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
    });
    }

    function getCookie(cname) { 
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    }
    return "";
    }
    });

    function resetForm() {

    var expired = new Date(today.getTime() - 24 * 3600 * 1000); // less 24 hours

    function deleteCookie(name)
    {
    document.cookie=name + "=null; path=/; expires=" + expired.toGMTString();
    }
    }
    </script>
```

what is wrong i am doing here? please help me.

Comment: in the function "deleteCookie" you are passing the path before the expired date, you should write the expire date before the path  ->     document.cookie=name + "=null; expires=" + expired.toGMTString(); path=/";

Comment: I passed "path=/" after "expires" now checked state is not keep after refresh without reset.

Comment: Are the cookies restored only after you refresh? Or are you not being able to reset them at all? If they are restoring only on refresh it could mean that the server is setting them in response. Also look into HTTP only and secured cookies if you are trying to send them back to the server.

Comment: Yes cookies restored after refresh or submit form.

Comment: I checked cookie is http only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

Instead of this:-

```
 <input type="reset" onclick="return resetForm();"/>
```

Change

```
 <input type="button" value ="Reset cookie" onclick= 'document.cookie = "username=; expires=Fri, 29 Jun 2018 00:00:00 GMT";'/>
```

Comment: have you put username variable properly??